# Long min limit in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings

Why does Visual Studio treats the constant `-2147483648` (`0x80000000`) as unsigned?

From what I know this value is still within min limit for `long`.

Example, if you compile the following:

```
long a = -2147483648
```

The compiler will issue the following warning:

```
warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned type
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kh09110.aspx

Comment: The relevant portion: "You can avoid C4146 by using INT_MIN from limits.h, which has the type signed int."

Comment: Possible duplicate of one of the following questions: [Why it is different between -2147483648 and (int)-2147483648](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12620753/995714), [large negative integer literals](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8511598/995714), [Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11536389/995714), [(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14695118/995714)

Comment: thank you, guys. I should have check msdn before posting.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the decimal constant here is not `-2147483648`, it's `2147483648` with the unary `-` operator applied to it.  In C, numeric constants don't include signs.

2147483648 is out of range for `long` on your implementation, so under the C89 rules this has type `unsigned long`.  Under the rules introduced in C99, it would instead have type `long long`.

To change this code to produce the value -2147483648 with type `long`, you can use:

```
long l = -2147483647 - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because maximum signed long could be 7FFFFFFF = 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111.

Comment: this does not really explain what's happening here