# How to make small signed integer literals that take into account 2s complement?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, integer, user-defined-literals

I've been trying to make signed literal short hands for `<cstdint>` types, for example, u8,  u16, etc...

I developed a function like this:

```
constexpr std::int8_t operator "" _i8(unsigned long long int value){
    unsigned long long int mask = 0xEF;
    if(value && mask == value){
        return static_cast<std::int8_t>(value);
    }else{
        throw std::out_of_range("");
    }
}
```

I then looked up and found that [`-` is actually not part of the literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511598/large-negative-integer-literals).  What this means for me is that the above code( if it included 128, right now it doesn't) wouldn't actually work correctly for -128.

When I try this out in godbolt

```
#include <type_traits> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdint> 
#include <bitset> 


int main(){

    std::cout << std::bitset<8>(static_cast<std::int8_t>(128)) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << static_cast<std::int32_t>(static_cast<std::int8_t>(128)) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << static_cast<std::int32_t>(static_cast<std::int8_t>(-128)) << std::endl; 
    std::cout << static_cast<std::int32_t>(-static_cast<std::int8_t>(128)) << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

I get `10000000`, `-128`, `-128`, and `128`

Technically using 128 could work in the above example, it would just force the value to be -128 on the output, but when they (correctly) add a negative, it will turn into 128, and not be a int8_t. I'd like errors on 128 with no negative, and no errors on 128 with negative.

I thought about making some sort of temporary object with `-` overloaded for it, and implicitly converting, but even with that, it won't work properly in template functions, so the unary - operator would have to return the base type, and I would somehow have to return  the base type switched on if the value is 128 or not, but I don't think that's possible.

I basically want the following to work:

```
template<typename T> 
foo(const T& bar, const T& baz); 

foo(127_i8, std::int8_t(32));
foo(-128_i8, std::int8_t(32));
```

and this to not work:

```
foo(128_i8, std::int8_t(32));
```

Comment: You've found one of the sharp edges in C++ (and in C).

Comment: A related question:  is there a way to tell if the implementation is using 2s complement or 1's complement?  All the platforms I've developed for have been 2's complement, but I know there are 1's complement platforms out there.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews AFAIK, C++20 now requires signed integers to be two's complement, see P1236R1.

Answer (score 1):

Even for C++20, where signed integers are now required to be two's complement, this is simply not possible as there is no such thing as negative integer literals. This means that mimicking a negative integer literal will always be a two-step process. There is no way to create a `-128_i8` without creating a `128_i8` first, and at that point (the first step), there is no knowing if some kind of negation operation will be applied to it later.

So, while we could do something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Wdc9z89hj) to make `static_assert(-128_i8 == -128);` compile successfully:

```
#include <cstdint>

struct [[nodiscard]] i8 {
    std::int8_t n;

    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr auto operator-() const noexcept -> i8
    { return {static_cast<decltype(n)>(-n)}; }

    [[nodiscard]]
    constexpr operator decltype(n)() const noexcept
    { return n; }
};

[[nodiscard]]
constexpr auto operator"" _i8(unsigned long long int n) noexcept -> i8
{ return {static_cast<decltype(i8::n)>(n)}; }

// note: this example assumes that the implementation defined
//   truncation does the right thing
static_assert(-128_i8 == -128);
static_assert((128_i8).operator-() == -128);
```

There is still no way of discerning `128_i8` from `-128_i8` at the point of creation of the user-defined literal. The best we can do here is to match the truncation behavior of the underlying integer type, as in:

```
static_assert(-128_i8 == 128_i8);
static_assert(static_cast<std::int8_t>(-128) == static_cast<std::int8_t>(128));
```